# FtpWebRequest Download File

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

The following code is intended to retrieve a file via FTP.  However, I'm getting an error with it.

```
serverPath = "ftp://x.x.x.x/tmp/myfile.txt";

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverPath);

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;                
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

// Read the file from the server & write to destination                
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) // Error here
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))            
using (StreamWriter destination = new StreamWriter(destinationFile))
{
    destination.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    destination.Flush();
}
```

The error is:

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)

The file definitely does exist on the remote machine and I am able to perform this ftp manually (i.e. I have permissions).  Can anyone tell me why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This paragraph from the [FptWebRequest class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) might be of interest to you:

> The URI may be relative or absolute.
>   If the URI is of the form
>   "ftp://contoso.com/%2fpath"  (%2f is
>   an escaped '/'), then the URI is
>   absolute, and the current directory is
>   /path. If, however, the URI is of the
>   form "ftp://contoso.com/path", first
>   the .NET Framework logs into the FTP
>   server (using the user name and
>   password set by the Credentials 
>   property), then the current directory
>   is set to /path.

Comment: Well, for me it was a matter of dealing with non-ASCII characters, like a # was in the URL, they have to be url encoded.

Answer (score 57):

I know this is an old Post but I am adding here for future reference. Here is a solution that I found:

```
    private void DownloadFileFTP()
    {
        string inputfilepath = @"C:\Temp\FileName.exe";
        string ftphost = "xxx.xx.x.xxx";
        string ftpfilepath = "/Updater/Dir1/FileName.exe";

        string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;

        using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
        {
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "P@55w0rd");
            byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);

            using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath))
            {
                file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                file.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
        }
    }
```

**Updated based upon excellent suggestion by Ilya Kogan**

Comment: Note that you should dispose of IDisposable objects. The easiest way to do this is to use the keyword `using`.

Comment: You are correct, I posted this response when I was rather new to C#

Comment: If you're going to use the `WebClient`, rather than the `FtpWebRequest`, you could use its [`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) method, rather than messing with a `FileStream`, which might be a little easier. There are some things that WebClient can't do, though (such as use `ACTV` rather than `PASV` FTP: `FtpWebRequest.UsePassive = false;`)

Answer (score 36):

### Easiest way

The most trivial way to download a binary file from an FTP server using .NET framework is using [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadFile(
    "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip", @"C:\local\path\file.zip");
```

---

### Advanced options

Use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest), only if you need a greater control, that `WebClient` does not offer (like [TLS/SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555), progress monitoring, ascii/text transfer mode, [resuming transfers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331133/850848#66154869), etc). Easy way is to just copy an FTP response stream to `FileStream` using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

---

### Progress monitoring

If you need to monitor a download progress, you have to copy the contents by chunks yourself:

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int read;
    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
    }
}
```

For GUI progress (WinForms `ProgressBar`), see:
[FtpWebRequest FTP download with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45269263/850848)

---

### Downloading folder

If you want to download all files from a remote folder, see
[C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848).

Comment: How did you come up with the number "10240" for the buffer size?

Comment: @Donald.Record It's a common practice for a file copy buffer to be in a magnitude of few KBs. It should be larger than a disk sector size. And I do not think that larger than 10KB helps anything. Though actually the [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto) uses a buffer of 80 KB.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private static DataTable ReadFTP_CSV()
    {
        String ftpserver = "ftp://servername/ImportData/xxxx.csv";
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpserver));

        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // use the stream to read file from FTP 
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        DataTable dt_csvFile = new DataTable();

        #region Code
        //Add Code Here To Loop txt or CSV file
        #endregion

        return dt_csvFile;

    }
```

---

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue!

My solution was to insert the `public_html` folder into the download URL.

**Real file location on the server:**

> myhost.com/public_html/myimages/image.png

**Web URL:**

> www.myhost.com/myimages/image.png

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
       private string host = "yourhost";
       private string user = "username";
       private string pass = "passwd";
       private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
       private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
       private Stream ftpStream = null;
       private int bufferSize = 2048;

        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);

            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);

            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception) {  }

            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }

        catch (Exception) {  }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverPath);
```

After this you may use the below line to avoid error..(access denied etc.)

```
request.Proxy = null;
```

Comment: proxy is nothing by default.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, [Microsoft recommends not using FtpWebRequest for new development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0):

> We don't recommend that you use the FtpWebRequest class for new development. For more information and alternatives to FtpWebRequest, see WebRequest shouldn't be used on GitHub.

The GitHub link directs to [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library) which contains a list of third-party FTP libraries, such as [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP).