# Upload file to FTP using C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, ftp

I try upload a file to an FTP-server with C#. The file is uploaded but with zero bytes.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dirPath = @"C:/Documents and Settings/sander.GD/Bureaublad/test/";

    ftp ftpClient = new ftp("ftp://example.com/", "username", "password");

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath,"*.*");

    var uploadPath = "/httpdocs/album";

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        ftpClient.createDirectory("/test");

        ftpClient.upload(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtnaam.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Gelieve uw naam in te geven !");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload file on ftp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151680/upload-file-on-ftp)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

The existing answers are valid, but why re-invent the wheel and bother with lower level [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest) types while [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient) already implements FTP uploading neatly:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
    client.UploadFile("ftp://host/path.zip", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, localFile);
}
```

Comment: PSA: webrequest is no longer recommended, this are now the [official alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library)

Answer (score 60):

### Easiest way

The most trivial way to upload a file to an FTP server using .NET framework is using [`WebClient.UploadFile` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip";
client.UploadFile(url, @"C:\local\path\file.zip");
```

---

### Advanced options

If you need a greater control, that `WebClient` does not offer (like [TLS/SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555), ascii/text transfer mode, active mode, transfer resuming, progress monitoring, etc), use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest). Easy way is to just copy a `FileStream` to an FTP stream using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
}
```

---

### Progress monitoring

If you need to monitor an upload progress, you have to copy the contents by chunks yourself:

```
var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int read;
    while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
    } 
}
```

For GUI progress (WinForms `ProgressBar`), see C# example at:
[How can we show progress bar for upload with FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6341024/850848#45931971)

---

### Uploading folder

If you want to upload all files from a folder, see
[Upload directory of files to FTP server using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44012637/850848).

For a recursive upload, see
[Recursive upload to FTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925131/850848)

Answer (score 50):

**.NET 5** [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-5.0)

```
async Task<FtpStatusCode> FtpFileUploadAsync(string ftpUrl, string userName, string password, string filePath)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
    }

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

**.NET Framework**

```
public void UploadFtpFile(string folderName, string fileName)
{

    FtpWebRequest request;

    string folderName; 
    string fileName;
    string absoluteFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    
    request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}", "127.0.0.1", folderName, absoluteFileName))) as FtpWebRequest;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UseBinary = 1;
    request.UsePassive = 1;
    request.KeepAlive = 1;
    request.Credentials =  new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    request.ConnectionGroupName = "group"; 

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Flush();
        requestStream.Close();
    }
}
```

How to use

```
UploadFtpFile("testFolder", "E:\\filesToUpload\\test.img");
```

use this in your foreach

and you only need to create folder one time

to create a folder

```
request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/{1}/", "127.0.0.1", "testFolder"))) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: The answer misses a call to `request.GetResponse()`. Without it, the upload won't (rightfully) work on some servers. See [How to: Upload Files with FTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me:

```
public virtual void Send(string fileName, byte[] file)
{
    ByteArrayToFile(fileName, file);

    var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ServerUrl + fileName));

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
    request.ContentLength = file.Length;

    var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    if (response != null)
        response.Close();
}
```

You can't read send the file parameter in your code as it is only the filename.

Use the following:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dir + file);
```

To get the file so you can pass it to the `Send` method.

Comment: hello,
I have a folder with files in it ..
how can I just upload it to an FTP server?
This code I do not know exactly how this works?

Comment: in foreach loop call this method with appropriate input.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static void UploadFileToFtp(string url, string filePath, string username, string password)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + fileName);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }

    var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Upload done: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: why do you set KeepAlive = false? Are you sure that it is nessesary to requestStream.Close()? You use requestStream inside using so i think it will close stream by its own.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example must change those to:

```
requestStream.Flush();
requestStream.Close();
```

First flush and after that close.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,this method will SFTP a file to a location within your network.
It uses SSH.NET.2013.4.7 library.One can just download it for free.

```
    //Secure FTP
    public void SecureFTPUploadFile(string destinationHost,int port,string username,string password,string source,string destination)

    {
        ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(destinationHost, port, username, new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password));

        var temp = destination.Split('/');
        string destinationFileName = temp[temp.Count() - 1];
        string parentDirectory = destination.Remove(destination.Length - (destinationFileName.Length + 1), destinationFileName.Length + 1);


        using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
        {
            sshclient.Connect();
            using (var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand("mkdir -p " + parentDirectory + " && chmod +rw " + parentDirectory))
            {
                cmd.Execute();
            }
            sshclient.Disconnect();
        }


        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ConnNfo))
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            sftp.ChangeDirectory(parentDirectory);
            using (var uplfileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(source))
            {
                sftp.UploadFile(uplfileStream, destinationFileName, true);
            }
            sftp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer seems like the only solution for my sftp. Waiting to test it.

Comment: Question was about `FTP`, not `SFTP`. and `SFTP` is completely different, NOT secure version of `FTP`.

Comment: Answered this question  8 years ago, one of my first answers. More of an example. Have to be very precise with  you folks haha. You don't know why I put that answer. Nothing to do FTP or SFTP . See my Inbox from stackoverflow. Have not visited the site for years haha.

Answer (score 1):

publish date: 06/26/2018

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
    public static void Main ()
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = 
(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", 
"janeDoe@contoso.com");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        byte[] fileContents;
        using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt"))
        {
            fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        }

        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status 
{response.StatusDescription}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way I've found is FluentFtp
You can find the repo here:
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP
and the quickstart example here:
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/Quick-Start-Example.

And actually the WebRequest class recommended by a few people here, is not recommended by Microsoft anymore, check out this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-5.0

```
// create an FTP client and specify the host, username and password
// (delete the credentials to use the "anonymous" account)
FtpClient client = new FtpClient("123.123.123.123", "david", "pass123");

// connect to the server and automatically detect working FTP settings
client.AutoConnect();

// upload a file and retry 3 times before giving up
client.RetryAttempts = 3;
client.UploadFile(@"C:\MyVideo.mp4", "/htdocs/big.txt", 
    FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite, false, FtpVerify.Retry);

// disconnect! good bye!
client.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that -

1. FtpwebRequest is missing.
2. As the target is FTP, so the NetworkCredential required.

I have prepared a method that works like this, you can replace the value of the variable ftpurl with the parameter TargetDestinationPath. I had tested this method on winforms application :

```
private void UploadProfileImage(string TargetFileName, string TargetDestinationPath, string FiletoUpload)
        {
            //Get the Image Destination path
            string imageName = TargetFileName; //you can comment this
            string imgPath = TargetDestinationPath; 

            string ftpurl = "ftp://downloads.abc.com/downloads.abc.com/MobileApps/SystemImages/ProfileImages/" + imgPath;
            string ftpusername = krayknot_DAL.clsGlobal.FTPUsername;
            string ftppassword = krayknot_DAL.clsGlobal.FTPPassword;
            string fileurl = FiletoUpload;

            FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl);
            ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
            ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
            ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileurl);
            ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
            int bytes = 0;
            int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
            System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
            System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
            while (total_bytes > 0)
            {
                bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
            }
            //fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            rs.Close();
            FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
            string value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
            uploadResponse.Close();
        }
```

Let me know in case of any issue, or here is one more link that can help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx