# ftpwebrequest.getresponse is throwing 550 access denied

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to figure out how to get this file uploaded to my ftp server in C#.  When it calls `getResponse()` on `ftpwebrequest` it is throwing an error that says "550 - access denied".  I cannot figure out why.  I can connect to the server with Filezilla just fine using the same credentials.

Here is my code that does the connection:

```
private void UploadFileToFTP(HttpPostedFile file, string server, string user, string pass)
    {
        string uploadUrl = server + file.FileName;
        string uploadFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        Stream streamObj = file.InputStream;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
        streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        streamObj.Close();
        streamObj = null;
        try
        {
            SetMethodRequiresCWD();
            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
            //ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftp.UsePassive = true;
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            FtpWebResponse CreateForderResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();

            if (CreateForderResponse.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.PathnameCreated)
            {

                string ftpUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadUrl, uploadFileName);

                FtpWebRequest requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl) as FtpWebRequest;

                requestObj.KeepAlive = true;
                requestObj.UseBinary = true;

                requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

                Stream requestStream = requestObj.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Flush();
                requestStream.Close();
                requestObj = null;

            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you connect to the same ftp site via file-zilla do you actually upload successfully using file-zilla

Comment: yes, uploading and downloading works fine with filezilla

Comment: try doing this using `WebClient` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp

Comment: can I do that with an httppostedfile?  I don't have a file path for the httppostedfile.

Comment: do you have a firewall running somewhere?

Comment: I have disabled my Kaspersky firewall.  I will try disabling my Windows firewall to see if that helps at all.

Comment: Getting same response after disabling Windows firewall as well.

Comment: Hi @dmikester1, are you attempting to connect to a FTP or FTPS?

Comment: I am connecting to a regular FTP server.

Comment: I've just noticed your  `FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);` is resoving to potentially to a file that doesn't exist, as you state your uploadURL is the server, and the name of the file you're attempting to upload. Hence a access denied?

Try just making it `string uploadUrl = server;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I tinkered around with this some more after reading through the comments here.  I went into my Kaspersky settings and disabled scanning of port 20 and 21.  Boom!  File is there.  Now it is coming across empty for some reason, so I will investigate that or come back for some help here! :)