# Ftp upload to Unix or Windows servers

Tags: c#, windows, unix, ftp

Looking at a way to upload a file on a Unix server as well as a Windows server.

All I find so far is to WebServers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp))...

Any tip?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are server ways to upload file in linux/window machine.
Easiest and safer way to run **sftp service** in your destination machine. And share credentials with user(client).

Destination machine will act as sft server and any machine could be sftp client.
This will work perfect while destination and source machine and different operation system.

Thanks,
Mohit M

Comment: Thank you. Just figured out that the link I sent works for windows, however not on Unix since the ftp server isn't enabled there. So will look into your solution on the how to! cheers