# FTP file To Server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I am currently using `FTPwebRequest` to move a local file over to a server.  I am able to FTP to the root directory at ftp://ftp.xxxx.com. But, whenever I try to FTP the file to a folder within that directory like: ftp://ftp.xxxx.com/firstfolder nothing happens. I don't get any hard halts in the code and I also setup a `FTPwebResponse` stating that the transfer is complete.

```
string dest = "ftp://username:password@ftp.xxxx.com/firstfolder/" + fileName;

ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(dest);
```

I have also tried using `%2f` to mimic the CD command.

Here are a few links I have been looking at with no luck:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariya/2006/03/06/changing-to-the-root-directory-with-ftpwebrequest

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91e2bed0-9e5e-4503-9e66-d224086e43a8/change-directory-with-ftpwebrequest

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `string dest = "ftp://username:password@ftp.xxxx.com/firstfolder/" + fileName;`

Comment: Hey @Gusman it was what you had. I typed it out wrong. Still doesn't work formatted like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload file to FTP using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: When you use FTP the file goes into a default startup folder depending on the login to the ftp site (or anonymous).  I suspect the folder is going into a different folder than where you are looking.  Try use an IE with url  ftp://ftp.xxxx.com (yes include ftp instead of http) and see if you can locate the file.

Comment: When I ftp to the root directory I can see it in a web browser. But when I use the /firstfolder/filename I don't see it in that directory.  I even copy and pasted the path from my code to make sure it was correct.

Comment: Gusman  I checked out the link you provided. It didn't provide me with a solution to my problem.  I tried using Webclient as well, but I need to FTP not to root or startup folder.

Comment: So I tried viewing the directory in a different web browser and behold the file exists.  With IE the file was not showing, but with google chrome the file did exist. Very weird, but I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

In IE the file did not appear in the servers directory.  I used google chrome and I was able to view the file successfully. It was uploaded the hole time.