# How I can upload file with ftp server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a host for my web site and this host have not enough space for my file and I get another host to save my file in this host I have ftp adress and username and pass

I find this code

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
```

but

how i can upload my file to another host with ftp and get url place of save file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you choose the path where you upload to ftp appending directories to the FTP address:

```
string CompleteDPath = "ftp://yourFtpHost/folder1/folder2/";

string FileName = "yourfile.txt";
```

And here you have a working example I found once:

```
WebRequest reqObj = WebRequest.Create(CompleteDPath + FileName);
The following script work great with me for uploading files and videos to another servier via ftp.

FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "" + username + "_" + filename);
ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileurl);
ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
int bytes = 0;
int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
while (total_bytes > 0)
{
   bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
   total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
}
//fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
rs.Close();
FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
uploadResponse.Close();
```

Extracted from here:

[Upload file on ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151680/upload-file-on-ftp)

Comment: what is ftpurl and username and filename

Comment: That is an example. In the FtpWebRequest you just send the URL string. The username and password are used in the Credentials line ;)

Comment: i say here FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "" + username + "_" + filename);

Comment: I know you mean there. Just replace "ftpurl + "" + username + "_" + filename" for your real URL, for example: FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost/myftpfolder/" + filename);

Comment: i upload my file and i get it on HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile now my file in uploadfile how i can use your answer for uploadfile

Comment: Not to forgot to add the following line:    fs.Position = 0;