# Force WebClient to use SSL

Tags: c#, .net, security

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365607/939213) giving the simple idea of uploading files to ftp by using `WebClient`. This *is* simple, but how do I force it to use **SSL**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTPS (FTP over SSL) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331665/ftps-ftp-over-ssl-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331665/ftps-ftp-over-ssl-in-c-sharp) by `Edward Brey` might answer your question. Instead of providing my own answer I will just copy what Edward says:

---

You can use FtpWebRequest; however, this is fairly low level. There is a higher-level class WebClient, which requires much less code for many scenarios; however, it doesn't support FTP/SSL by default. Fortunately, you can make WebClient work with FTP/SSL by registering your own prefix:

```
private void RegisterFtps()
{
    WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("ftps", new FtpsWebRequestCreator());
}

private sealed class FtpsWebRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate
{
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        FtpWebRequest webRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(3, 1)); // Removes the "s" in "ftps://".
        webRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Once you do this, you can use WebRequest almost like normal, except that your URIs start with "ftps://" instead of "ftp://". The one caveat is that you have to specify the method, since there won't be a default one. E.g.

```
// Note here that the second parameter can't be null.
webClient.UploadFileAsync(uploadUri, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, fileName, state);
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks interesting.

Comment: This works for FTPS, but *FTPS* (FTP+SSL) is a rare animal. If you're trying to connect to an *SFTP* server (file transfer over SSH), which is a much more common scenario, WebClient can't do that. You'd have to look at a separate library such as SSH.NET.

Comment: @bobince a) Thanks. But FTP+SSL is what I want. b) I don't get notified of your comment unless you add the `@MyName`. Thanks again.

Comment: but does this need to validate any certificates , or are all auto-accepted ?

Comment: I have not come up with this myself. I suggest you follow the linked answer and ask the original poster himself. My first guess would be that you need to implement something to accept invalid certificates. Something along the lines of `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

Comment: @bigworld12 When you `EnableSsl`, by default the client validates certificates using the OS's public key infrastructure. Be aware that if you bypass validation by blindly accepting any server certificate, you become vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack.