# C# FTP with WebClient Error: The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, webclient, ftps

The purpose of my code is to upload some data to a FTP location.

With my code I keep getting an error stating that the remote server requires SSL. I am using a .NET version greater then 4. All the other posts suggest I add the `ServicePointManager` code that I have below.

The exception occurs on `client.UploadData`.

Still no dice. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (sender,certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
byte[] data = stream.ToArray(); //Data I want to upload to FTP location

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*Username*", "*Password*");
    client.UploadData("ftp://file.example.com/Content/file", "STOR", data);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, `WebClient` does not support FTP over TLS (FTPS) natively (it actually does support it *internally*, but has no API to enable its use).

Setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` cannot help. And definitely do not set it to `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`!

---

- either register `ftps://` prefix as shown for example here: [Force WebClient to use SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31432402/850848).
- or instead of `WebClient`, use `FtpWebRequest`, which supports FTP over TLS natively.

  Use a code like this:
  [Upload and download a binary file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848)

  And just add

  ```
  request.EnableSsl = true;
  ```