# Using WebClient.UploadFile with TLS (1.1 or 1.2)

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp, webclient

Just wondering if `WebClient.Uploadfile` is TLS secure either by 1.1 or 1.2. I found the following line of code and have installed in my application.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

The following line of code does the work in my application

```
WebClient.UploadFile("ftp://xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxx/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
```

Is there any way to test for security here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nice [*WinSCP*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) library ([assemblies source](https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-6.1.1-Automation.zip)) for secure FTP connection:

```cs
using var session = new Session();
session.Open(new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,
    TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = "xx:xx:xx:...",
});
session.PutFiles("local path", "remote path").Check();
```

You can set by `FtpSecure`, if TLS should be [explicit or implicit](https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/support/kb/189). Implicit TLS requires different port, while explicit TLS gives possibility to use the same port for unsecure and secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient.UploadFile` is not secure. Setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` does not change anything about it.

See [FTPS (FTP over SSL) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848).