# How to download FTP files with automatic resume in case of disconnect

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I can download FTP files, but the download code does not have a resume facility and multi part files download. Because there are file larger than 500 MB, I can't download them continuously, because the connection gets closed and it starts download from beginning. I wanted my code a resume facility if it gets disconnected.

The code I am using is:

```
public string[] GetFileList()
{
    string[] downloadFiles;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    try
    {
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
            new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/"));
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            result.Append(line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(response.StatusDescription);
        return result.ToString().Split('\n');
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        downloadFiles = null;
        return downloadFiles;
    }
}

private void Download(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    try
    {
        //filePath = <<The full path where the file is to be created.>>, 
        //fileName = <<Name of the file to be created
        //             (Need not be the name of the file on FTP server).>>
        FileStream outputStream =
            new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
            new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileName));
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long cl = response.ContentLength;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        ftpStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Before you start downloading check for the existence of the file on the local filesystem. If it exists, then get the size and use that for the [`ContentOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset) member of the `FtpWebRequest` object. This functionality may not be supported by the FTP server, though.

Answer (score 0):

A native implementation of FTP download resumption using the `FtpWebRequest`:

```
bool resume = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        FileMode mode = resume ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create;
        resume = false;
        using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\local\path\file.dat", mode))
        {
            var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.dat";
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.ContentOffset = fileStream.Position;
            using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        resume = true;
    }
}
while (resume);
```

---

Or use an FTP library that can resume the transfer automatically.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) does. With it, a resumable download is as trivial as:

```
// Setup session options
var sessionOptions = new WinSCP.SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword"
};

using (var session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Resumable download
    session.GetFileToDirectory("/home/user/file.zip", @"C:\path");
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*