# FTP file (.csv) download gets truncated

Tags: ftp, download, ftpwebrequest

This downloads a .csv file using FTP. The file is 46k on the server. When I download, it gets truncated to 44k. I have no idea why ... when I view the data in Excel, it is cut short. I increased the buffer to 4096 but no dice (this probably isn't the problem).

I originally grabbed the following code and tweaked it from: [Downloading Files Using FTPWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519290/downloading-files-using-ftpwebrequest)

Any thoughts appreciated !  Thanks.

```
    private void DownloadFile(string userName, string password, string ftpSourceFilePath, string localDestinationFilePath)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];            

        FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpSourceFilePath, userName, password, false);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localDestinationFilePath, FileMode.Create);

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                               

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    private FtpWebRequest CreateFtpWebRequest(string ftpDirectoryPath, string userName, string password, bool keepAlive)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpDirectoryPath));

        //Set proxy to null. Under current configuration if this option is not set then the proxy that is used will get an html response from the web content gateway (firewall monitoring system)
        request.Proxy = null;

        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = keepAlive;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Always use notepad too look at your CSV file, and set binary to false

Comment: What happens if you add a fileStream.Close() just after the while loop? Or if you make your buffer so big that the whole file fits in one read?

Comment: @rene > the fileStream.Close() worked! bravo ... if I could, I'd accept your answer but I guess we can't accept comments ... thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
private void DownloadFile(string userName, string password, string ftpSourceFilePath, string localDestinationFilePath)
{ 
    int Length = 2048;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);     

    FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpSourceFilePath, userName, password, false);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localDestinationFilePath, FileMode.Create);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
        //if (bytesRead == 0)
          //  break;
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

         fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks man. I was missing fileStream.Close() which caused the truncation ... the "while" logic is actually ok ...