# WebClient UploadFile Does Not Work

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I'm using C#, WinForm, This code.

I have modified the XML file and uploaded it to the web server, but the XML file is missing from the web server.

but debugging is good working and WebClient Download works well.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("id", "password");
     client.UploadFile("http://abcdef.com/test.xml", @"C:\test.xml");
}
```

Comment: And the server side code looks like? I think you should read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, I think I understood it. So do you need to write code on the server to use the code?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes :-) The WebClient uploads the data, then you need server-side code to do what you want with it (save as a file or whatever...) I make this an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a file via HTTP POST with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebClient.UploadFile Method uploads the data, then you need server-side code to do what you want with it (save as a file or whatever...)

Take a look at this on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Additional question: Can I use code only on the client without writing code on the server?

Comment: The Client cannot save files on the server, but if you have a FTP-Server you can use that. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109823/upload-file-and-download-file-from-ftp

Comment: Ok. 
Thank you for your answer.