# Replacing files with WebClient

Tags: webclient

I'm testing the following code for replacing files on a https site via C# code, but it has no effect and 
generates no exception. (Downloading files works fine).

```
try
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        //www.testsite.com is just an example - testing is done with an actual site:
        client.UploadFile("https://www.testsite.com/testfolder/testpage.html", @"C:\testuploads\testpage.html");
        //same effect using the 3-param version - no effect + no exception:
        //client.UploadFile("https://www.testsite.com/testfolder/testpage.html", System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, @"C:\testuploads\testpage.html");
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This post mentioned the need for server-side code:
[WebClient UploadFile Does Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198940/webclient-uploadfile-does-not-work)

But how does an FTP client tool such as FileZilla Client accomplish this? Surely it doesn't install server-side
code. (FileZilla Client replaces the file without issue).

Comment: I'm sure you're not using *HTTP* with FileZilla. And yes, you need a server side component if you want to post files.

Comment: With FileZilla Client, I'm comparing it to "FTP over TLS" - what would be the equivalent of this then in C# code?  Or at least effective enough to replace files on an https site.

Comment: Well you would use FTP in this case also

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Is that still using WebClient, but specifying "ftp" instead of "https" ?

Comment: Yes, WebClient can handle FTP URLs so just change that. Not sure if it will use TLS by default, do run a search about that.