# The provided format of the path is not supported

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ftp

I am trying to upload a file via FTP

> The provided format of the path is not supported

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Guardar_registro(Models.CascadingModelLevantamiento model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
      var NombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      string name = Path.Combine("" + NombreArchivo);
      string ftpfullpath = Path.Combine(@"ftp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xx" + @"/test/" + name);
      FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
      ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@xx.com", "xxx");
      ftp.KeepAlive = true;
      ftp.UseBinary = true;
      ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
      FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ftpfullpath);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
      fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      fs.Close();
      Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
      ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      ftpstream.Close();
 }
```

Comment: `System.IO.File.OpenRead(ftpfullpath);` will attempt to read a path on the local machine at the specified path of the FTP server.

Comment: I already do it in `FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead (ftpfullpath);` ...... the file comes `HttpPostedFileBase` since I use MVC

Comment: Unrelated, but important: you need to [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) the streams you create and organize your code (instead of putting all in one place) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not re-invent the wheel, try something like this:

```cs
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
    client.UploadFile("ftp://host/path.zip", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, localFile);
}
```

Resource link: [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient)

Comment: I already used that but I get this error:
`Exception during a WebClient request`

Comment: @Morquecho you need to add more error information is it the same error as in your question?

Answer (score 0):

What goes to `File.OpenRead` must be a valid local (Windows) path. Not FTP URL.

Something like

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\local\path", NombreArchivo);
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename);
```

---

Though as correctly commented in the other answer, way easier is to use `WebClient.UploadFile`.

See [Upload file and download file from FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13109823/850848).