# Visual Basic FtpWebRequest downloading files?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

What I have:

```
Dim ftploader As System.Net.FtpWebRequest =
    DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
        "ftp://ftp.cabbageee.host-ed.me/nim/Vardelatestmessage.txt"),
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

ftploader.Credentials =
    New System.Net.NetworkCredential("Insert Username here", "Insert password here")
```

I am trying to download this `.txt` file to my `c:` drive. I already have a connection, so how can I save that `.txt` file? Also, how can I upload a file? I already tried `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile`, but it is only possible to download/upload once, as I have no idea of how to get rid of that connection.

Answer (score 3):

The most trivial way to download a binary file from an FTP server using VB.NET is using [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile):

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
client.DownloadFile(
    "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip", "C:\local\path\file.zip")
```

---

If you need a greater control, that `WebClient` does not offer (like [TLS/SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555), ascii/text transfer mode, [resuming transfers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331133/850848#66154869), etc), use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest). Easy way is to just copy an FTP response stream to `FileStream` using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

Using ftpStream As Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),
      fileStream As Stream = File.Create("C:\local\path\file.zip")
    ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream)
End Using
```

---

If you need to monitor a download progress, you have to copy the contents by chunks yourself:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

Using ftpStream As Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),
      fileStream As Stream = File.Create("C:\local\path\file.zip")
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(10240 - 1) {}
    Dim read As Integer
    Do
        read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If read > 0 Then
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position)
        End If
    Loop While read > 0
End Using
```

For GUI progress (WinForms `ProgressBar`), see (C#):
[FtpWebRequest FTP download with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45269263/850848)

---

If you want to download all files from a remote folder, see
[How to download directories from FTP using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22626766/850848)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) and then you'll have access to the response stream which will include your content, you could then write that stream into the text file you want to save.

There seems to be a [pretty well fleshed out sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17202/Simple-FTP-demo-application-using-C-Net-2-0) (it's in C# but I think should be fairly easy to translate to VB).

Answer (score -1):

try this instead:

```
 Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
 Dim webfilename As String = "http://www.whatever.com/example.txt"
 Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(myWebClient.OpenRead(webfilename))

 gCurrentDataFileContents = file.ReadToEnd()

 file.Close()
 file.Dispose()
 myWebClient.Dispose()
```