# Copy files from ftp to remote desktop using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have to copy some files from **ftp** to another **remote** desktop computer. I am doing this as:

```
File.Copy("ftp://IPAddress:Port/MyFolder/MyFile.dll", @"IPAddress\MyLocation");
```

But this is not working. I think, it happened because the folder in the remote desktop where i have to paste my file is not a **shared** folder.

so , i want to know how can we copy files from ftp to remote desktop folder which is not shared?

also, the **ftp** and **remote desktop** requires the credentials (Password). pls also tell me how can i handle credentials in my code?

Comment: Have you tried using drive$ for the IPAddress\MyLocation? i.e. C$ will give you access to remote pc's C: drive

Comment: Even this question in SO has sample code in it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781654/ftpwebrequest-download-file

Answer (score 1):

The System.Io.File class does not support URI's or the FTP protocol, only access to local file system and shared folders.

Please check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx) on how to upload files with FTP using the .NET Framework.

Comment: i have successfully download file from FTP using ftpwebrequest and ftpwebresponse classes. Now, i have to paste this file to the folder of a remote server PC and this folder is not Shared. Is it possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with folder sharing. FTP is a separate protocol that needs a separate server application like for instance Serv-U (Windows) or proftpd (Linux). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_server_software