# FTP client in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create an FTP client in C# and Visual Studio 2010. Can you please suggest me some good links to start ? I want to use latest version of C# so I am looking for latest code samples for help so that I can get benefit of already made code.

Thanks.

Comment: This link can help: https://github.com/componentpro/ftpclient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse` .Net classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx

2) Many other libraries : [Free FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/c-free-ftp-client-library-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this http://netftp.codeplex.com/. This library has been last updated as of today as Aug. 5 2013.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

I think this is what you're looking for, I think it would give you a neat head start!

Comment: @Priyank: Should I use FTPWebRequest and Response or Libraries ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I wrote a FTP client using the FTPWebRequest methods, It's working good in production so far, most of the libraries weren't free!

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: I recommend FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse .Net classes.