# How can i upload text to my own website automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

In general i want that every 5 minutes my application will upload a text to my website. So if the current page in my website is empty after uploading the text i will see on the page the text.

This is my example website:

```
http://rhodan.wix.com/chocolade#!blank/c1236
```

Empty page.

This is the code I'm trying to use to upload the text to the site:

```
private void SaveTToWeb()
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string myFile = @"C:\Temp\file.txt";
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                client.UploadFile(@"http://rhodan.wix.com/chocolade#!blank/c1236", "PUT", myFile);
                client.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

I don't get any exceptions or errors but i don't see the text in the text file on my page.

Comment: If you are trying to upload a file you will usually need FTP creds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading a file to remote server, one must ask himself couple of question.
Does the remote server support it ?
How do you communicate with the remote host (HTTP, FTP, REST API) ?
I see that you write "PUT", does wix support what you are trying to do ?
In addition, you would probably need credentials (username/password/key) in order to upload a file to a specific remote server.
From quick reading, I see you should upload the files via FTP.
http://www.wix.com/support/forum/flash/other/other/accessing-my-server-for-upload-of-files
And here's a link might be useful
[FTP client in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734083/ftp-client-in-c-sharp)