# what is the C# equivalent of net::ftp in Perl

Tags: c#, perl, ftp

```
 $ftp = Net::FTP -> new ( $addr, Passive => 0, Timeout => $timeout )
         or die "Failed to connect to FTP (w/ active, timeout): $addr";
```

what would be the C# equivalent to implement a new ftp client like the above, also what about login and controlling the transfer modes like :

```
 $ftp -> login ( $usr, $pwd )
   or die "Failed to login to FTP: " . $ftp->message;

  { $ftp -> ascii();  }
  { $ftp -> binary(); }
```

Comment: Your question looks similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371964/1521179). Also, have you taken a look at the MSDN documentation for the corresponding [.Net classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx)? (or are you using Mono instead of .Net?)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.FtpWebRequest.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Analogous to Net::FTP in Perl would be FtpWebRequest in C# -that is, a library that speaks the protocol so you don't have to do a lot of heavy lifting yourself.  Then your code is going to look like

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(...);
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...);
ftpRequest.UseBinary   = true;
ftpRequest.UsePassive  = true;
```

(This is not real code, just typical elements you would have.)  See the MSDN reference for the chapter and verse.