# FTP request download a file and delete immediately

Tags: c#, ftp

I have got a code to download a file using ftprequest

```
FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost/Source/" + fileName);
requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("khanrahim", "arkhan22");
requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + fileName, FileMode.Create);  

int Length = 2048;
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);               

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
  writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
}   

responseStream.Close();             
writeStream.Close();
```

Now my need is that i need to delete the file from ftpserver once download is complete using the same requset.

I did try appending 
    requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.deleteFile;
before closing the request ..But it is not working.
How can i delete the file using the same request.

Comment: after you appended that did you execute it with `FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();` ?  just a guess but maybe that will do it

Comment: s i did do that but i got an error lik "cannot do this after server req is complte"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects created by `WebRequest.Create` can be used for exactly one request. Since there is no "GET and DELETE" method in FTP you need to create another `FtpWebRequest` with the same configuration and send delete request with that new `FtpWebRequest`.

Comment: In that case how can i avoid re login

Comment: @user2799127 - you can't - with `FtpWebRequest` you can't issue 2 commands and have to re-login for every request. If you need to talk to the same server with multiple requests - consider [searching for full FTP client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library).