# How to fetch file by FTP via squid proxy using .NET Core (FtpWebRequest)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, proxy, ftp, squid

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.proxy?view=netcore-3.1 `FtpWebRequest` does not support proxy with .NET Core. Is there an alternative?

I need to access a FTP file via some squid proxy (i.e. FTP over HTTP) with proxy authentication (NTLM).

This is example code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.ubuntu.com/");
var proxy = new WebProxy("my.squid.host", 8080);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("squid_user", "squid_pass");
request.Proxy = proxy;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

var result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you replace squid host/user/pass in this code with yours, you will see this works fine with this csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But it no longer works with .NET Core:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no other FTP implementation in .NET framework than `FtpWebRequest`. And `FtpWebRequest` itself is deprecated and won't be improved. You have to use a 3rd party FTP client library.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest#remarks and
- https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md (which points to [Free FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1371964/850848))

---

In general, you can use [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) or *my* [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Though neither supports NTLM authentication (a requirement you have added later). I'm not aware of any other free widely used .NET FTP library.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful answer (and BTW thanks for WinSCP). FluentFTP doesn't supports HTTP 1.1 proxies -- but no NTLM (forgot to mention that I need that). I'm looking into alternatives.

Comment: Did you mean that *"FluentFTP **does** support HTTP 1.1. proxies, but not NTML"*?

Comment: That's the way it looks: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP/Proxy/FtpClientHttp11Proxy.cs#L72