# Uploading files to a web hosting (godaddy) through c #

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ftpwebrequest

I'm here to ask you for help.

I need that my c # application can upload a file to a folder located in my website hosted by godaddy.

Now I'm using a FtpWebRequest to do this but I need to set the ftp credential and this means that everyone can see the FTP account and password ...

The same for another function that I need, I need to download a file from a webserver but the url is visible! I'm using the WebClient.OpenRead method to do this.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: you mean others can see it in source code? then you may have to store credential in database.

Comment: I mean, by using an app like wireshark you can see the FTP request with the username and password shown.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't recomment FtpWebRequest (see-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-6.0).
They recommend alternatives (read here: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md)
-> For FtpWebRequest: use third party FTP client (e.g. from this list).
It appears FluentFTP has FTPS client (see: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP)

Seems like someone already answered this question.  Again, see this answer-> [Free FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library)