When uploading a file, the error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" occurs
I'm trying to make a copy of the file and upload it to the server. But when trying to download, this error occurs.
private static void CopyDBForService()
{
    using(var fdb = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        var srcFile = "computerservice.db";
        var destFile = "./Service/computerservice.db";

        File.Copy(srcFile, destFile, true);
    }
}

private static void UpdateDBAsync()
{
    CopyDBForService();
    try
    {
        using var client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.UploadFile("ftp://example.com/computerservice.db", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, "./Service/computerservice.db"); //HERE
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
        MessageBox.Show(status);
    }
}


Seems like it's opened in exclusive mode and in use. Whatever is using it, you must first stop it (and probably give it some time) before you can copy it.

The file is copied normally, the problem occurs in this line: client.Upload File("ftp://example.com/computer service.db", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, "./Service/computerservice.db");

I would imagine that the file is still locked by your copy operation. When you catch the exception, add a delay and then try again. I'd wager that the file will be released at some point. You may as well add a delay before trying for the first time too.

Also mind, that Microsoft discourages the use of WebClient for new development and advertises HttpClient as replacement.

^^ Which does not apply for FTP, of course. So if this is for .Net 6 and later, I just found that they actually recommend 3rd Party FTP clients. => DE0003: WebRequest shouldn't be used , and that links to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library which is an SO-Question without accepted answer ... I really don't know what they were thinking, there.
